# Leaflet Summary widget

Tags: leaflet

Is there a way to display Summary of numeric attributes from a  layer in the visible map extent, [like ArcGIS Summary widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-summary.htm)  ?